# How to move to the next page in Facebook JSON response using iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

In Facebook iOS SDK, I can ask for queries like this:

```
[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andDelegate:self];
```

But often Facebook will give a limited JSON response with a URL to be used to request to move to earlier dates, for example. So in the JSON response, I'll have:

```
data =     ( /*things here... status updates, photos, etc...*/
    );
paging =     {
        next = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?sdk=ios&sdk_version=2&access_token= <something>&until=2010-12-04";
        previous = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?sdk=ios&sdk_version=2&access_token=<something>&since=<something>";
    };
```

What I'm wondering is... How do I go to the previous URL? Does the SDK provide an interface to do this?

EDIT: If possible, I actually want answer with Graph API, as Facebook is currently deprecating the REST API.

BONUS: If anyone can explain the time format that's returned by Facebook. I have `2010-09-13T00%3A25%3A16%2B0000` as an example.

Comment: By the way, your time format is just URL Encoded.  Decode it and you get this "2010-09-13T00:25:16+0000".  More obvious now? :)

Comment: Yes! I didn't know how I've missed that. It's been a year and a half since I posted this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

all what you need that add a method to the Facebook subclass or itself

```
- (void)requestWithURLString:(NSString *)fullURL
               andHttpMethod:(NSString *)httpMethod
                 andDelegate:(id <FBRequestDelegate>)delegate {
    [self openUrl:fullURL params:nil httpMethod:httpMethod delegate:delegate];
}
```

ps the second param "httpMethod" may be always @"GET" you can omit it

Comment: WOW, works very well! Thank you very much! BTW why isn't Facebook SDK build this in? Do you know if it's a planned update?

Comment: No, I didn`t find any tasks about that feature at https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues
but You can be first who done it )

Comment: This answer no longer applies to the latest version of the Facebook SDK.  I've added a new answer explaining how to accomplish it in the latest version.

Answer (score 6):

With **Facebook's iOS SDK version 3** out, the original answer no longer applies to the current version.

I had to do some digging, because the new version doesn't make this any easier.  I found an example of how to get this done in the FBGraphObjectPagingLoader class that the new SDK provides to help do this for tables.  It's incredibly ugly, but I assume that it's the "recommended" method since it's what they use.

Here's my slight modification of their code (found originally in [FBGraphObjectPagingLoader's followNextLink method](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/src/FBGraphObjectPagingLoader.m))

```
FBRequest *request = [[[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:FBSession.activeSession graphPath:nil] autorelease];
FBRequestConnection *connection = [[[FBRequestConnection alloc] init] autorelease];
[connection addRequest:request completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
     // Do some stuff
 }];

// Override the URL using the one passed back in 'next'.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest* urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
connection.urlRequest = urlRequest;

[connection start];
```

You could of course modify their library and encapsulate this in the class itself if you wanted to.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't looked into iOS SDK 3.0 yet, but it seems like they aren't making this any easier.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
[appDelegate.fb requestWithGraphPath:@"me/home"
                           andParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"2011-01-27T04%3A48%3A50%2B0000" forKey:@"since"]
                         andDelegate:self];
```

Notice that, in the `paging` portion of your feed, the `next` and `previous` URLs differ just by one query parameter (`until` and `since`). You can use the values you grab from this to get the next and previous page of results.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmm not working for me, I have an error from facebook: could not parse 2011-01-27T04%3A48%3A50%2B0000 into a date or time. Any other ideas?

Comment: Hmm, that's weird... It worked for me before. I'll try to figure this out too, as I need it for a project of mine.. Will keep you updated..

Comment: Search for "since and until" on this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/api. It says you can use "almost any valid date format." I've tried using "since=yesterday" and "until=yesterday" and they both work. I also tried using a timestamp (converted here: http://www.epochconverter.com/) and that also gave me a valid time format. So... it looks like you can convert it to a Unix timestamp. Though I think it's weird that they'd offer the date in the format above and not accept it... Needs more investigating..

Comment: I actually don't quite understand the time format. The one that I'm testing is 2010-09-13T00%3A25%3A16%2B0000, when I tried epochconverter.com it says that it's 1st Jan 1970. Something must definitely be wrong in here... I'll investigate a little bit more as well.

Comment: @donkim It seems that Gaj has done it. Although I won't say it's a particularly elegant solution (hacking the SDK), I'll see if Facebook has this method in the pipeline.

Comment: That's a great solution. I actually *just* got it to work with the solution above (you have to use the `until` parameter, extract the date, then put it in the dictionary using `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" extractedDate]`. But you know, I like that solution and I agree that it should be included in the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can get the result by calling the function in api
I used below code to get the statuses of users in your case you can use stream.get method you can found it here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.get/

```
NSMutableDictionary * params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [params setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", appDelegate.user_id] forKey:@"uid"];
    [params setValue:@"150" forKey:@"limit"];
    [params setValue:@"results" forKey:@"callback"];


    [_facebook requestWithMethodName: @"status.get"
       andParams: params
       andHttpMethod: @"POST"
                         andDelegate: self];
```

You can use this code for you purpose.

Comment: This will get the first 150 statuses right? How do I get the next 150?

Comment: You can put a limit infinite like 100000 or more but the max count of records facebook provide is about 1 year statuses. You can get more then that by using any of facebook api as they are not providing the data more then a year ago.

Comment: what do you mean i can get more than that using any facebook api?

Comment: Sorry Actually I want to write "You can't get more.."

Answer (score 0):

At least as far as the date format goes, its a variant of RFC 3339 format.  As far as I know, iOS doesn't have a pre-defined formatter of that type.

I create a date formatter and keep it around (they're are strangely slow to create) so I can easily convert them when working with FB data.

```
        NSDateFormatter * sRFC3339DateFormatter = nil;
        NSLocale * enUSPOSIXLocale;

        sRFC3339DateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        enUSPOSIXLocale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease];

        [sRFC3339DateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
        [sRFC3339DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssZ"];
        [sRFC3339DateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
```

Once you have such a formatter, you can easily convert back and forth.

```
NSDate* myDate = nil;
myDate = [sRFC3339DateFormatter dateFromString:@"2011-01-27T04%3A48%3A50%2B0000"];
```

Breaking the   URL up into a dictionary of strings is pretty straightforward with NSURL methods.